# C language:Removing a node from a BST of strings

Tags: c, string, function, struct, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a function, that will remove a node from the BST, which will be `==` with the word that the user inserts in the program, meaning that I ask the user, which word would he like to remove, he types that in and saves it under the variable `key[MAX]` in `main`. But something goes wrong when trying to delete the node, so my program just dies

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 15

typedef struct BST
{
    char data[MAX];
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
    int count;
} node;

node *create();
void insert(node *,node *);
void preorder(node *);
struct BST *minValueNode(struct BST *node)
{
    struct BST *current = node;


    while (current && current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}
struct BST *deleteNode(struct BST *root, char key[MAX])
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    int cmp_rezult=strcmp(root->data, key[MAX]);

    if (key[MAX] < root->data[MAX])
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);
    else if (key[MAX] > root->data[MAX])
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);

    else
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)//it the node has no children or only 1
        {
            struct BST *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            struct BST *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }

        //if the node have 2 kids
        struct BST *temp = minValueNode(root->right);

        //sorting
        root->data[MAX] = temp->data[MAX];

        //deleting
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->data[MAX]);
    }
    return root;
}


int main()
{
    char key[MAX];
    char ch;
    node *root=NULL,*temp;

    do
    {
        temp=create();
        if(root==NULL)
        {
            root=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root,temp);
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to enter more(y/n)?");
        ch=getch();

    }
    while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');

    printf("\nPreorder Traversal: ");
    preorder(root);
    printf("\nWho shall we delete:");
    scanf("%s", &key[MAX]);
    deleteNode(root, key[MAX]);
    return 0;
}

node *create()
{
    node *temp;
    printf("\nEnter data:");

    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    fgets(&temp->data,MAX,stdin);

    temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
    temp->count=1;
    return temp;
}

void insert(node *root,node *temp)
{
    int cmp_rezult=strcmp(temp->data,root->data);
    if(cmp_rezult<0)
    {
        if(root->left!=NULL)
        insert(root->left,temp);
        else
        root->left=temp;
    }
    if(cmp_rezult>0)
    {
        if(root->right!=NULL)
        insert(root->right,temp);
        else
        root->right=temp;
    }
    if(cmp_rezult==0)
    {
        root->count++;
    }
}

void preorder(node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%s Repeats:%d time(s)",root->data, root->count);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `struct node` actually defined anywhere. There is only `struct BST`, which is aliases to type `node`. E.g. this code can't possibly compile because `struct node` is a myth. I'm gonna go out on a limb and suggest that wherever you acquired this, they used different struct names and you never resolved them to yours. Further evidence of that comes from the mythic member `key` which is likewise not in your defined node type, yet repeatedly referenced.

Comment: @WhozCraig not really, sir, I tried to rename them to `struct BST ...` but It still gives me the same error

Comment: If you did as you claim, i.e. there is no longer any `struct node` mentioned anywhere in code, either in usage or declaration, it cannot *possibly* give the "same error" unless you're no longer compiling the same source code. There are *plenty* of other errors in this code, but that error cannot possibly surface if there is no `struct node` referenced

Comment: @WhozCraig I've updated the program so now It doesn't give me any errors when compiling, but it still does not work as intended for me

Comment: You have a completely wrong understanding of how arrays work. `key[MAX]` in most places here does not mean what you think it does.

Comment: Does this code run?

Comment: @LinuxGeek yes it does, as intended though? Nope

Comment: @LinuxGeek no, codeblocks

Comment: @Vlad No, I said you first need a better understanding of how arrays work. But alright, here's an example: `if(key[MAX] < root->data[MAX])` It compares the `char` *after* `key` with the `char` *after*  `root->data`. `scanf("%s", &key[MAX]);` will make `printf` store the input past the end of your buffer. The fact you don't do this consistently is a sign of cargo cult programming

Comment: Can you add multiple elements and print it? Because I can't with your code.

Comment: @LinuxGeek you mean in the BST? Yes it does it for me with no problems

Comment: @Vlad The code doesn't run on my machine, if it runs fine on your machine, that code should help you.

Comment: @EmanuelP hm, i see what you're meaning there, thank you. That's my particular fault because my monky mind always forgets about `fgets` and `gets` and this particular comment of yours helped me to remember it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the same code as above, but, in `BST *deleteNode` I've updated the code at `cmp_result` so now it's written correctly, after that I've updated the `if` statements under the `cmp_result`, also I've updated the code in the same function, going from `root->data[MAX] = temp->data[MAX];` to `strcpy(root->data,temp->data);`, which is the correct way to do it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 15

typedef struct BST
{
    char data[MAX];
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
    int count;
} node;

node *create();
void insert(node *,node *);
void preorder(node *);
struct BST *minValueNode(struct BST *node)
{
    struct BST *current = node;


    while (current && current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}
struct BST *deleteNode(struct BST *root, char key[MAX])
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    int cmp_result = strcmp(key, root->data);

    if (cmp_result < 0)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);
    else if (cmp_result > 0)
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);
    else
    {

        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            struct BST *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            struct BST *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }

        
        struct BST *temp = minValueNode(root->right);

        strcpy(root->data,temp->data);

        
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->data);
    }
    return root;
}


int main()
{
    char key[MAX];
    char ch;
    node *root=NULL,*temp;

    do
    {
        temp=create();
        if(root==NULL)
        {
            root=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root,temp);
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to enter more(y/n)?");
        ch=getch();

    }
    while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');

    printf("\nPreorder Traversal: ");
    preorder(root);
    printf("\n\nWho shall we delete:");
    fgets(key,MAX,stdin);
    printf("\n%s", key);
    deleteNode(root, key);
    printf("\nPreorder Traversal: ");
    preorder(root);
    return 0;
}

node *create()
{
    node *temp;
    printf("\nEnter data:");

    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    fgets(temp->data,MAX,stdin);

    temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
    temp->count=1;
    return temp;
}

void insert(node *root,node *temp)
{
    int cmp_rezult=strcmp(temp->data,root->data);
    if(cmp_rezult<0)
    {
        if(root->left!=NULL)
            insert(root->left,temp);
        else
            root->left=temp;
    }
    if(cmp_rezult>0)
    {
        if(root->right!=NULL)
            insert(root->right,temp);
        else
            root->right=temp;
    }
    if(cmp_rezult==0)
    {
        root->count++;
    }
}

void preorder(node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%s Repeats:%d time(s)",root->data, root->count);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how an answer on SO should be. This is just a "code dump". Please explain what you did.